# Django REST Framework move all urls to router

Tags: python, django, rest

I have little experience in python. Please could you help me. There is an old project which has the following structure

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.static import serve
from rest_framework import routers # i added it

import home.views

router = routers.DefaultRouter() # i added it


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home.views.HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/v2/', include('api.v2.urls', namespace='api-v2')),
    url(r'^help/', include('helps.urls', namespace='helps')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')), # i added it
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)) # i added it
]
```

I would like to make REST API so that you can see all possible routes. So i try to add `rest_framework.urls`. As I understood it is necessary to use `VeiwSet` to add it to router. I do not quite understand how I can use what I already have to see links in a REST API? Or for each link i need to create a Veiwset?

For example `api.v2.urls` contains next: (similar in helps.urls, etc)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
import api.v2.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^data/info', api.v2.views.info_data),
    url(r'^visits$', api.v2.views.visits),
    url(r'^additional_info/', api.v2.views.additional_info),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

a `Viewset` combines several views into a same class. You can have it for example to provide CRUD api for one of your Django model.

I recommend to read http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

You can register the `Viewset` in a router. I will generate an url for every view of the views

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

in urls.py

```
from myapp.views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='user')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

If you print the `router.urls`

```
for url in router.urls: print(url)
```

You will see something like:

```
<RegexURLPattern user-list ^ users/$>
<RegexURLPattern user-list ^ users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^ users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>
<RegexURLPattern user-detail ^ users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>
```

It shows the url for every view of the viewset

You can also have regular `View` for your REST API. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/ which can be added to your urls like any usual Django view.

I hope it helps

Comment: thx, but i saw this example. The fact is that the project uses as_views() and APIView not Veiwset. I wanted to find a way to not change the existing code because i have many routes(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to declare explicitly the urls that you want to show:

This is what i have in one of my projects:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Your stuff: custom urls includes go here
    url(r'^api/$', api_root, name='api-root'),    
] 


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAdminUser, ))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'apples': reverse('my-api:oranges-all'),
        'oranges': reverse('my-api:oranges-list'),

    })
```